# Im having trouble with codehs swapping 9.5.6

Tags: python

This is the assignment: 
Use your knowledge of unpacking and identity to complete the function swap_lists. This function should take two lists as arguments and swap their values.

Your starter code calls your function like this:
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]
print "Before swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)
swap_lists(list_one, list_two)
print "After swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)

Note that the starter code will not run, since the function definition is empty!
Hint: It won’t work to just do something like this:
   first, second = second, first
You will instead need to use a control structure to swap individual elements in the lists!

This is my code: 
    # swap_lists
    # -----
    # This function takes two lists of equal length 
    # as arguments and swaps their values.
    def swap_lists(first, second):
        if len(first) != len(second):
            print "Lengths must be equal!"
            return

```
    # Write your code here...
    for i in range(3):
        second[i]
    for i in range(3):
        first[i]= second[i]

list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = [4, 5, 6]

print "Before swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)

swap_lists(list_one, list_two)

print "After swap"
print "list_one: " + str(list_one)
print "list_two: " + str(list_two)
```

What do I need to add for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

after # write your code:

`elif len(first)==len(second):
        for i in range(len(first)):
            first[i], second[i] = second[i], first[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    def swap_lists(first, second):
       f = [second, first]
       print("After swap")
       print("list_one: " + str(f[0]))
       print("list_two: " + str(f[1]))

    list_one = [1, 2, 3]
    list_two = [4, 5, 6]

    print("Before swap")
    print("list_one: " + str(list_one))
    print("list_two: " + str(list_two))

    swap_lists(list_one, list_two)
```